# Deploy web app to Azure but still showing Microsoft page instead of the webform created

Tags: asp.net

I am attempting to publish a web app (mvc project) from visual studio to azure but I keep getting the blow page [image]

I am not sure what to do. I've added WebForm2.aspx in the default document (on azure) and added the below tag in the **web.config** page but still no luck
[image]

Any ideas please?

Comment: You say it's an MVC project but that's a webforms page.. Have you downloaded your App Service's publish profile and published from Visual Studio using it ?

Comment: Hi sh1rts, thank you for responding. While creating the project I had opted for MVC and then added a webform to it hence the mention of MVC.

That being said. I had initially logged into VS using the same account I have on azure, so whenever I went to publish it automatically listed the one web app from my azure as a deploy option. 

Also forgive my ignorance, I am very green on azure. it looks like everything is working if only the url would actually display my webform.

Comment: Can you use Kudu to check it's actually been deployed correctly ? In your App Service in the Azure Portal go to Advanced Settings, Go, use the Debug Console and navigate to site\wwwroot and check that your files are actually there.

Comment: Thank you! I went back and reviewed everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use a Response.Redirect from your WebForms code with the right URL which gets routed to your controller in question, I guess in your case, that is:

```
Response.Redirect("/Home/Index");
```

Or even better you could make an extension method for HtmlHelper that handles your routing:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString WebFormActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string ruoteName, object routeValues)
        {
            var helper = new UrlHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext);

            var anchor = new TagBuilder("a");
            anchor.Attributes["href"] = helper.RouteUrl(routeName, routeValues);
            anchor.SetInnerText(linkText);
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(anchor.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Your Routes:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{

    routes.MapPageRoute(
          "Webforms-Route", // Route name
          // put your webforms routing here
         );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "MVC-Route", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
            );
    }
```

You would then just pass in your route to your HtmlHelper and you will get the correct route.

Comment: Thank you so much Purvesh. I just leaned something totally new with the Routing. Site i finally displaying properly.